# what is the strongarm variable addititonal_settings_active_tab_*

Tags: features, strongarm

I am using the Features and Strongarm module to move my work between sites. I am using them as a way of version controlling changes made in the database (as Configuration Management module has many issues.)

I am trying to understand what the following settings are, which module (or core) creates them, and should they be passed from site to site:

```
 additional_settings__active_tab_chapter
 additional_settings__active_tab_committee
 additional_settings__active_tab_document
 additional_settings__active_tab_event
 additional_settings__active_tab_jcr_article
 additional_settings__active_tab_jcr_issue
 additional_settings__active_tab_news
 additional_settings__active_tab_page
 additional_settings__active_tab_success_stories
```

The last piece of these settings ie: 'chapter' are the names of the content types on the site. Should I be passing these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the vertical tab that is "active" when the node edit form loads. Export as needed (I usually don't).

FWIW, i used 'drush vget' to take a look at the variables value and that made it pretty easy to figure out its purpose. ([Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush))